# App Center is crashing

Tags: applications

App center was too good before. But the last update it's being crashed while searching for an app. It crashes right after typing one or two characters. And even when I click on the categories say 'Development' it gets crashed. Any solution. Thank you.

The error can be seen when launching appcenter from the terminal, after typing 1 character in the search field, the following log appears:
`Client.vala:241: The package id's '' are not valid`

Comment: Crashes when clicking categories too.

Comment: I reproduced Jaydemir's observation also on my system. I also noticed that, after being able to type more than three characters, when removing the characters one by one using backspace, the Appcenter crashes as soon as there are only two characters left.

Comment: Apparently the bug has been identified, fixed and approved by their dev team. There is no release date though (as of positing this comment). Here's the link to bug report - https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1646020

Comment: It crashed after exactly two typed characters. Since yesterday the bug is fixed. Close the question.

Answer (score 0):

True, it starts happening after installing some input update.

Make sure you restart and run update again . It will fix itself

Answer (score -1):

Try: `sudo apt install synaptic`
Open synaptic and update.

Comment: or gnome-software works just fine too

Answer (score -1):

New `appcenter` 0.1.3 is out.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install appcenter
```

Comment: You don't need to remove it, the recommended way is `sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt install appcenter`

Answer (score -2):

I wish I had a full answer, but I had asked this very same question before, and it doesn't show up in the question list when I'm not signed in, so I don't know if it was just 'dismissed', or what.

What I DO know, is that when I run the appcenter in terminal, then I type two characters into the search bar, the app crashes because of a "Segmentation fault"

```
joe@HP-G62:~$ appcenter
[INFO 18:53:31.544223] Application.vala:155: App Center version: 0.1.2
[INFO 18:53:31.544336] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-47-generic
```

This is what happens when I input two characters:

```
[FATAL 18:53:40.229094] Client.vala:241: The package id's '' are not  valid
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

What I also found is that if I type in 3 or more characters before it has the chance to crash, it works just fine. What this tells me is that it isn't the *search function* that has the bug, but rather the handling of the first two characters that are put into the search bar.

At this point, I hope a developer comes across this post and knows exactly where to look from here.

Comment: This is not an answer. This is more suited as an addendum to question posted.

Comment: Technically he asked if there was "Any Solution". I mentioned a workaround where typing 3 characters avoids the crash. Unfortunately, I'm not a developer so I can't provide a full solution. App Center is broken, and App Center needs to be fixed. Point blank.