# App Center crashing when typing on search and on specific categories click

Tags: appcenter

When I run appcenter and type two letters into the search bar the application crashes with the following error.
The same error (without the 3rd line) occurs when I click in **specific** categories.
For example it crashes on Internet but not in Graphics category.

```
[INFO 09:11:19.229139] Application.vala:155: App Center version: 0.1.2
[INFO 09:11:19.229221] Application.vala:157: Kernel version: 4.4.0-51-generic
[FATAL 09:11:24.781323] Client.vala:241: The package id's '' are not valid
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

This bug is also covering in other posts which I am trying to merge here.

[App Center is crashing](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9470/app-center-is-crashing)

[App center crashes when typing into search bar](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/app-center-crashes-when-typing-into-search-bar)

---

edit: 
This is a confirmed bug (#1646164) you can view bellow the bug report.
So I suppose we are just waiting for the fix.

[Bug Report here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1646164)

Answer (score 1):

New appcenter is out,0.1.3, sudo apt-get remove appcenter && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install appcenter

Comment: That just sound wrong - simple upgrade should fix it without uninstalling/reinstalling (you even suggest remove instead of purge so config files are kept). Do you have any reason for reinstalling instead of just upgrading?

Comment: Update could be enough, but I prefer to uninstall, update and reinstall. They are my own customs. The important thing of the information I shared was the new version that corrected the problems of the previous one. Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved. I just downloaded the updates and it does not crash when you insert 2 characters or search through the categories :)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/8050)

Comment: @lemonslice on the other hand the question should've been a bug report, really..

Comment: Yes it should have been, and it has been marked as such